# ¿que funcion cumple el siguiente codigo? {1:N0} C#

Tags: c#

```
namespace pregunta_1._4esta
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int n;
            Console.WriteLine("INGRESE UN NUMERO");
            n = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("{0}!=**{1:N0}**", n, Factorial(n));
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
        static double Factorial(int n)
        {
            int i = 2;
            double fac=1;
            while(i<=n)
            {
                fac *= i;
                i++;
            }
            return fac;

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Y cual es el problema? debes agregar una pregunta a cerca de un error o duda en especifico

Comment: [Composite Formatting](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/composite-formatting)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All estas aplicando `formato` al numero que resulte de `Factorial()`

[Cadenas con formato numérico estándar](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings)

como observaras en la documentacion el `N` aplica un `formato numerico` en este caso con `cero decimales`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Entiendo el `string.Format()` conoces como funciona, en cada `{}` al poner un numero indica la posicion del parametro asignara en ese lugar

Answer (score 1):

```
Console.WriteLine("{0}!=**{1:N0}**", n, Factorial(n));
```

Cuentas con la variable **n**, y el resultado de **Factorial(n)**.

Ambos valores se reemplazan en las cadenas **{0}** y **{1:N0}**, **N0** aplica un formato al texto similar a **8,175,133**.

El orden es muy importante.